# At (@) sign is written as double angle quotation marks(«) on a linux VM running on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard, virtual-machine, keymapping

I installed VMWare and downloaded Kali Linux from Offensive security and my at(@) sign is written as double angle quotation marks(«) instead.
My Keyboard settings are on German language and MacBookPro.
How do i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the Keyboard Model you can fix it in the GUI:

Go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Change the Keyboard Layout to German -> Change the Keyboard model to Apple laptop.

Or in the terminal:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

and then choose German as language and Apple laptop as Keyboard model.